# swift_unknownRelease Crash - SwiftHTTP

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

I have suddenly started observing the below crash on a new update to one of my apps. It seems to be happening quite frequently, and is confusing as I have made no changes to this section of the code in the last 6 months. I did wonder if [this](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-696) (EXC_BAD_ACCESS on returning a throwing Dictionary) Swift radar bug might be relevant, if the crash is due to forming the params dictionary for this request.

**Update**
This build was created using Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3. [SwiftHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) is v1.0.4. I see crashes with the production binary on iOS 8.3.0, 9.3.0 and 9.3.1. This issue is most prevalent (87%) on iPhone 6, 6 Plus and 6s. I have tried to reproduce this issue using Xcode Zombies (as per [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544)) but it did not show any `message sent to deallocated instance` messages in the console.

The crash occurs in performing a PUT update in a helper class I have for the [SwiftHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) library.

**Error**

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000020
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x100d6d8f8 swift_unknownRelease + 24
1  SwiftHTTP                      0x100b07298    _TTSf4g_n___TTSg5Ps9AnyObject____TFE9SwiftHTTPSa11createPairsfGSqSS_GSaVS_8HTTPPair_ + 700
2  SwiftHTTP                      0x100b002f4 _TFE9SwiftHTTPVs10Dictionary11createPairsfGSqSS_GSaVS_8HTTPPair_ + 2000
3  SwiftHTTP                      0x100b00f90 _TTWu0_Rxs8HashablerGVs10Dictionaryxq__9SwiftHTTP21HTTPParameterProtocolS1_FS2_11createPairsfGSqSS_GSaVS1_8HTTPPair_ + 112
4  SwiftHTTP                      0x100b0178c _TFE9SwiftHTTPCSo19NSMutableURLRequest16appendParametersfzPS_21HTTPParameterProtocol_T_ + 396
5  SwiftHTTP                      0x100af14a4 _TTWV9SwiftHTTP23HTTPParameterSerializerS_21HTTPSerializeProtocolS_FS1_9serializefzTCSo19NSMutableURLRequest10parametersPS_21HTTPParameterProtocol__T_ + 40
6  SwiftHTTP                      0x100af8ccc _TTSf4gs_n_n_g_n_d___TZFC9SwiftHTTP4HTTP3NewfzTSS6methodOS_8HTTPVerb10parametersGSqPS_21HTTPParameterProtocol__7headersGSqGVs10DictionarySSSS__17requestSerializerPS_21HTTPSerializeProtocol__S0_ + 624
7  SwiftHTTP                      0x100af5758 _TZFC9SwiftHTTP4HTTP3PUTfzTSS10parametersGSqPS_21HTTPParameterProtocol__7headersGSqGVs10DictionarySSSS__17requestSerializerPS_21HTTPSerializeProtocol__S0_ + 76
8  MyApp                   0x1001274c0 SwiftHTTPUtilities.PUT(String, auth : String, params : [String : AnyObject]?, model : String, mode : APIUtilities.ApiRequestType, object : AnyObject?) -> () (SwiftHTTPUtilities.swift:52)
9  MyApp                   0x100154e90 APIUtilities.(apiRequest(String, mode : APIUtilities.ApiRequestType, object : AnyObject?) -> ()).(closure #3) (APIUtilities.swift:76)
10 MyApp                   0x100152f70 partial apply for APIUtilities.(apiRequest(String, mode : APIUtilities.ApiRequestType, object : AnyObject?) -> ()).(closure #3) (APIUtilities.swift)
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x18364d4bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x18364d47c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x183652b84 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
14 CoreFoundation                 0x183bb8dd8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
15 CoreFoundation                 0x183bb6c40 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
16 CoreFoundation                 0x183ae0d10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
17 GraphicsServices               0x1853c8088 GSEventRunModal + 180
18 UIKit                          0x188db5f70 UIApplicationMain + 204
19 MyApp                   0x10026d508 main (AppDelegate.swift:25)
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x18367e8b8 (Missing)
```

**SwiftHTTPUtilities** (which is a helper class to interact with the open source library [SwiftHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP))

```
    func PUT(apiPath: String, auth: String, params: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>?,model: String, mode: APIUtilities.ApiRequestType, object: AnyObject?) {        
            do {
//SYMBOLICATED CRASH REPORT IDENTIFIES BELOW LINE FOR EXC_BAD_ACCESS
                let opt = try HTTP.PUT("\(apiPath)", parameters: params, headers: ["*removed*"])
                opt.start { response in
                    if let err = response.error {
//                        print("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                        self.delegate?.didGetServerResponse(false, response: nil, error: response.error, model: model, mode: mode, object: object)
                        return //also notify app of failure as needed
                    }
//                    print("opt finished: \(response.description)")
                    //print("data is: \(response.data)") access the response of the data with response.data

                    self.delegate?.didGetServerResponse(true, response: response.data, error: nil, model: model, mode: mode, object: object)
                }
            } catch let error {
//                print("got an error creating the request: \(error)")
                self.delegate?.didGetServerResponse(false, response: nil, error: nil, model: model, mode: mode, object: object)
            }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try to clean and build? Sometimes the crash isn't actually a crash in swift.

Comment: This crash is being observed in a production binary on the App Store. I haven't been able to replicate the crash on my physical device yet (i.e. triggering this function doesn't crash for me) but have been seeing the reports coming in on Crashlytics.

Comment: Ok. Was it built on Swift 1.0 or 2.0? And Xcode version?

Comment: Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to SwiftHTTP defaulting to HTTPSerialisation. The below line is how to specify JSON serialisation, which fixed the bug for me.

```
let opt = try HTTP.New("\(apiPath)", method: .PUT, parameters: params, headers: ["Authorization": "edit"], requestSerializer: JSONParameterSerializer())
```